# Who died in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

I have been hearing a lot of people say that "Nobody dies in One Piece", yet we have seen many people die like Ace, many of the antagonists' parents, etc. So it made me curious to all the people that ever died in One Piece. The answer should not include unnamed characters and focus on introduced characters that were confirmed to have died.

Comment: From the Top of my head: Portugas D. Ace died aswell as his mother Portogas D. Rouge, Whitebeard died, Monet died along with most people that remained on Punk Hazerd, Then there's Gol D. Roger (obvious), Clover and all the people from Ohara together with Jaguar D. Saul. Corazon died and so did the Water D. Family... And in a way Bartholemew Kuma died aswell.

Comment: I also had the same question..I mean people are brought back from dead if the need is to save one of the Stawhat crew..I mean their even their boat came to save them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a total list of the deceased to this point in One Piece:

**NOTE THERE ARE SPOILERS CONTAINED BELOW READ AT OWN RISK**

**A**

> [image]

**B**

> [image] [image] [image]

**C**

> [image] 
>  [image]
>  [image]

**D**

> [image] [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

**E**

> [image]

**F**

> [image] [image]

**G**

> [image]  [image] [image]   [image]

**H**

> [image]   [image]   [image]  [image]   [image]   [image]   [image]

**I**

> [image]

**J**

> [image]   [image]  [image]  [Joy Boy](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Joy_Boy)

**K**

> [image]   [image]   [image]  [image]   [image] [image] [image]   [Koshin](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Koshin)    [image]   [image]

**L**

> [image]  [image]

**M**

> [image]  [image]   [image]  [image] [image]  [image]   [image]  [image]   [Mr. 7](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._7_(Previous))    [image]

**N**

> [image]   [image]  [image]

**O**

> [image]   [image]  [image]

**P**

> [image]   [image]   [image]   [image]   [image]

**R**

> [image]  [image]  [image]   [image]   [image]   [image]  [image]

**S**

> [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]   [image] [image]

**T**

> [image]  [image]   [image] [image]

**V**

> [Vander Decken](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vander_Decken)   [image] [image]

**W**

> [image]   [image]

**Y**

> [image]

**Z**

> [image] [image]

Comment: The list is much longer than expected. Thank you very much for compiling this list. To summarize there are 64 manga deaths, 7 one-shot deaths, 8 anime-only deaths, 13 movie deaths and 1 video game death. That's a lot for a manga that *never kills people*.

Comment: I thought they might not be needed but went ahead and added them just to be safe lol

Comment: Ok sorry for spamming lol, but I just realized. Going Merry's not in the list ㅠ_ㅠ.

Comment: I didn't know whether to add the ship or not since it was not an actual breathing thing and more of a spiritual type being

Comment: Spoilez:  Gol D Rodger Dies

Comment: hmmm didnt also the skeleton guy die (although before he became a skeleton guy)? before he met ruffy.

Comment: You mean brook, in a way he did die.  I still miss Kuma who died aswell

Comment: @ChenOrihara Kuma is technically alive. If he was death, the Paw fruit would have reborn by now. Brook could be argued, because his spirit didn't go to afterlife yet.

Comment: Please avoid lengthy discussion in the comments, perhaps it would be best to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Why are these images? I don't recognize half of them...

Comment: As far as I know, it was never said that the 2nd under V died. The 1st under V definitely didn't die. It can be seen in jail after having been defeated. This is based on the manga, though, not sure about the anime.