# Has Luffy ever killed anyone?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, there is a lot of blood and fights as we saw on the death of

> Ace.

However, did Luffy ever actually kill any person?

Comment: based on this [list](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26478/who-died-in-one-piece), I think Luffy never killed anyone

Answer (score 18):

No, he never killed anyone. The reason why he never kills anyone is that he is leaving them another chance to achieve their dreams. This was also stated by Oda in [SBS vol. 4](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_4):

> D: How come Luffy never kills his enemies? Throughout "One Piece" manga so far, he didn't kill Mohji and Helmeppo, but Axe-arm Morgan was killed by Zoro, why is that?
>
> O: Hmm! That's a very good question. First, I have to announce that Morgan is still alive. He's currently in jail, where he was placed by his former subordinates. Why doesn't Luffy kill his enemies? Because in that era, everyone uses their lives to fight for their dreams. For an enemy, when their dream has been shattered, it is the same as losing a fight, and as painful as death. I believe, for a pirate not to kill an enemy, it's giving them a 2nd chance to fight for their dreams.

Answer (score 6):

Luffy kills the primary antagonist in the film *One Piece: Baron Omatsuri and the Secret Island* which is *One Piece Movie 6*.  This film, however, is one of the several non-canon films such as the more recent *Heart of Gold* and *Gold*.  It is very dark and surreal for *One Piece*.  That is even if you ignore the good guy who looks like Hitler.

An interesting comment on Reddit mentions that he is actually the one who finally "kills" the Going Merry.  That is a little different than what you mean because the Going Merry itself is not really alive (though it has a spirit) and it is already dying.

Answer (score 1):

When thinking logically about that question I concluded, that even if he doesn't intend to kill, there is no way he can avoid it. Just think about how fast he moves and how much of an impact his attacks do have. It is hard to believe that none of the numerous low-level enemies has ever suffered fatal injuries by that brute forces. Think of all the ships, walls and other hard stuff he is able to shatter with his bare hands. Not to mention countless enemies that are pushed from great heights - or off a ship. If you go overboard at high sea, you will most likely die after a few hours, even if you're not a Devil Fruit user.

So even if you take into account that - like in most anime - people tend to be a lot tougher than in reality and the "physical laws" of Luffy's world may be more generous towards the inhabitants, the answer has to be: Yes! Albeit it may not have been his intention, Luffy most certainly has killed a lot of people. Most of them are Marines, I assume. Just because he uses blunt force and no weapons, he is no less deadly. A car is blunt too. But if it hits you at 50mph...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to this post but, He killed multiple guards at impel down when he threw them into the pool of blood on Level 4, and he has also killed some marines as well. When he used Giant Pistol, and when the bullets bounced off of him and hit the marines.

> He also killed Kaido in the new Chapter of One Piece by hitting him into magma in the ground.

Comment: Kaidou has not been confirmed dead *yet*.

Answer (score 1):

In One Piece film: Z, Luffy orders Franky to fire the cannon on front of the Sunny. This attack hits many ships of the new marines, destroying all of them. Before the screen flashes and the ships are shown disintegrating, the faces of many new marines are shown. While LUFFY didn't kill these men, his actions clearly influenced their deaths.

Answer (score 0):

He could have accidentally killed someone when hitting and pushing large numbers of people. Although it is more likely with Zoro who makes slashing wounds, whereas Luffy's attacks leave bruises.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

However,

> he is directly involved in the scheme to assassinate Big Mom which fails in chapter 868-869

Answer (score -1):

Luffy has never killed anyone according to me, but if he killed the primary antagonist in movie six, maybe he did. Oda did state he doesn't kill anyone though, so maybe he knocked him out. So there's a strong chance he didn't kill that guy from movie six.

I normally see him knock his enemies out though, but it's true that Rob Lucci needed surgery after their fight in volume 44.

Comment: Can you point us to where Oda said Luffy doesn't kill anyone? Answers on Stack Exchange need sources for statements like that.