# How many people has Luffy killed?

Tags: one-piece

At Impel Down, Luffy kicks the guards into the big pool of lava-looking stuff. I counted 11 people killed by this, but I know I am missing some.

How many people has Luffy killed in total?

Comment: Related: [Has Luffy ever killed anyone?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38819/20275), which more-or-less goes against your analysis

Comment: @Wondercricket: none of the answers in the related question contradicts the OP's analysis. In particular, one answer also mentions the guards at Impel Down.